# kanjidic 2 xpath for getting nanori on Python

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, xpath, xml.etree

I'm currently working on a django project working with kanjidic2 xml file (http://nihongo.monash.edu/kanjidic2/index.html). I am using xml.etree.ElementTree to map xml information. However I got stuck when working with <reading_meaning> level. Here is a sample of an entry at kanjidic2:

```
<character id="9">
<literal>&#36898;</literal>
<codepoint>
<cp_value cp_type="ucs">9022</cp_value>
<cp_value cp_type="jis208">16-9</cp_value>
</codepoint>
<radical>
<rad_value rad_type="classical">162</rad_value>
</radical>
<misc>
<grade>9</grade>
<stroke_count>10</stroke_count>
<stroke_count>9</stroke_count>
<freq>2116</freq>
</misc>
<dic_number>
<dic_ref dr_type="nelson_c">4694</dic_ref>
<dic_ref dr_type="nelson_n">6054</dic_ref>
<dic_ref dr_type="halpern_kkd">4002</dic_ref>
<dic_ref dr_type="halpern_kkld_2ed">2774</dic_ref>
<dic_ref dr_type="heisig">2417</dic_ref>
<dic_ref dr_type="heisig6">2497</dic_ref>
<dic_ref dr_type="oneill_names">1516</dic_ref>
<dic_ref dr_type="moro" m_vol="11" m_page="0075">38901X</dic_ref>
</dic_number>
<query_code>
<q_code qc_type="skip">3-3-7</q_code>
<q_code qc_type="sh_desc">2q7.15</q_code>
<q_code qc_type="four_corner">3730.4</q_code>
<q_code qc_type="deroo">2555</q_code>
<q_code qc_type="skip" skip_misclass="stroke_diff">3-4-7</q_code>
</query_code>
<reading_meaning>
<rmgroup>
<reading r_type="pinyin">feng2</reading>
<reading r_type="korean_r">bong</reading>
<reading r_type="korean_h">&#48393;</reading>
<reading r_type="ja_on">&#12507;&#12454;</reading>
<reading r_type="ja_kun">&#12354;.&#12358;</reading>
<reading r_type="ja_kun">&#12416;&#12363;.&#12360;&#12427;</reading>
<meaning>meeting</meaning>
<meaning>tryst</meaning>
<meaning>date</meaning>
<meaning>rendezvous</meaning>
<meaning m_lang="es">encuentro</meaning>
<meaning m_lang="es">cita</meaning>
<meaning m_lang="es">encuentro casual</meaning>
<meaning m_lang="es">encontrarse</meaning>
<meaning m_lang="es">reunirse</meaning>
<meaning m_lang="es">citarse</meaning>
<meaning m_lang="es">verse por casualidad</meaning>
</rmgroup>
<nanori>&#12354;&#12356;</nanori>
<nanori>&#12362;&#12358;</nanori>
</reading_meaning>
</character>
```

I have no issues getting other level data into python dictionaries with the following code:

```
for i in character:
 if i.tag =='dic_number':
        dictionariesDict = {}
        dictionaries = root.find(".//character[@id='"+id+"']//dic_number")
        for dictionary in dictionaries:
            dictionariesDict[dictionary.get('dr_type')] = dictionary.text
```

However, when it comes to `reading_meaning` tag, I certainly don't know how to get nanori tags on one dictionary, `r_type="ja_on"` attributes in another, `reading r_type="ja_kun"` in another and meanings in another (ideally one dictionary per language).
I have tried with all kind of xpaths and when I print the root.find I get the tags, but when I loop for creating the dictionary, I just get empty dictionaries.

Thank you in advance for your help and patience.

Comment: WHat's the connection between `dict_ref` and `meaning`? They look unrelated.

Comment: None. I used it as an example of how I have been getting data, but that was it.

Comment: Let me know if the answer helps please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath will get `reading[@r_type="ja_kun"]`, second `meaning` element and all `nanori` elements at once
`(//reading[@r_type="ja_kun"] | //meaning[2] | //nanori)`

```
xmllint --xpath '(//reading[@r_type="ja_kun"] | //meaning[2] | //nanori)' test.xml | sed -e 's/></>\n</g'
<reading r_type="ja_kun">&#x3042;.&#x3046;</reading>
<reading r_type="ja_kun">&#x3080;&#x304B;.&#x3048;&#x308B;</reading>
<meaning>tryst</meaning>
<nanori>&#x3042;&#x3044;</nanori>
<nanori>&#x304A;&#x3046;</nanori>
```

Tested on bash and python

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.parse('test.xml')
>>> doc.xpath('(//reading[@r_type="ja_kun"] | //meaning[2] | //nanori)')
>>> arr = doc.xpath('(//reading[@r_type="ja_kun"] | //meaning[2] | //nanori)')
>>> for e in arr:
...     print(e.text)
... 
あ.う
むか.える
tryst
あい
おう
```

Using `xml.etree.ElementTree` you should try the xpath parts in the "OR" one by one

Comment: Just one question (as I'm a newbie on... everything :P):
On the code I first loop on all `character` tags looking for an specific id. Then, I loop over all child tags and use `if i.tag ==` to get a certain information. On this case, that `if` would only be `if i.tag == 'nanori'` ignoring the tags `reading_meaning` and `rmgroup`?

Comment: Depends on what xpath and module you decided to use. intermediate tags will not be present on found list, check by printing tag while iterating. If using etree as in the answer, then all tags will be found then you can do if-elseif-elseif as needed and pick info from all found tags. Makes sense?